# A Freiman-type of question

Tags: nt.number-theory

Recently I have bumped in the following question. This is not my field of research, but it looks to me very much related to Frieman-type of theorems.

Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $S$ be a subset of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ of cardinality $\ell$ with $s<n/2$, for every $s\in S$. (If needed, suppose that $\ell\leq n/6$.)
Consider $$X=\{(x,y)\in S\times S\mid x<y\textrm{ and }(x+y\in S \textrm{ or } n-x-y\in S)\}.$$

Can you give an upper bound on $X$ in terms of $n$ and $\ell$? (I am mostly interested in the asymptotic of this upper bound: when $n$ tends to infinity and $\ell\leq n/6$.)

Comment: Seems you can have $X=(0.5+o(1))l^2$, (almost) regardless of $n$: if $n$ is divisible by $2l$, then letting $d:=n/(2l)$ and taking $S$ to be the arithmetic progression $S=\{d,...,ld\}$ you have $x+y\in S\cup(n-S)$ for all $x,y\in S$.

Comment: you are right! Silly of me for not noticing this. Thanks.